# Adding custom legends

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

How do I add custom legends on seaborn chart? I am new to seaborn and matplotlib, and custom legends with handles and labels are really confusing.

```
for target in targets:
    sns.distplot(target[['sepal length (cm)']], hist=False, rug=True, label = target)
    plt.legend(unique_vals)

sns.distplot(target[['sepal length (cm)']==1], hist=False, rug=True)
```

I have added the above function to create the chart and label. And then I have added one more distribution plot. How do I add label for the second distribution plot?

Comment: Have you tried just use `plt.legend()` after finishing all your plots besides configging each plot with a label?

Comment: Yes, i have tried that. What it does is, it gives me list of values in the column as legends.

Comment: Eventually plt.annotate helped me create a legend, while i still struggled with creating a legend

Comment: You got list of values in the column as legends is because you define label as `label = target`.`label` will be used as plot legend. Try to assgin `label` with a string value.

Comment: The first one is not giving me a problem but when i used label in second plot even as a string it gives me list of values in the column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give more details about your program and data, since the below example plots the legend rightly even without `fig.legend()`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np


targets = []

for i in range(3):
    target = np.random.rand(10)
    targets.append(target)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, target in enumerate(targets):
    sns.distplot(target, hist=False, rug=True, label=i)

sns.distplot([ i for i in targets[0] if i > 0.3], hist=False, rug=True, label=len(targets))

#fig.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]